# How can I link MongoDB collections in FastAPI and implement the pydantic model using pymongo or motor?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, fastapi, pydantic

Please, can some show me how to do this in fastapi?

Sample collections

User Collection:

```
{
    "_id" : "object ID",
    "name": " str", 
    "email": " str"
}
```

UserProfile Collection:

```
{
    "_id" : "object ID",
    "first_name": "str", 
    "last_name": "str"
}
```

Company Collection:

```
{
    "_id" : "object ID", 
    " name" : "str", 
    " dept" : "str"
}
```

Questions:

1. How do I use one to many to link these schemas using pymongo or motor?
2. How do I represent that in pydantic model too?

Comment: did you take a look at pydantic doc(https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) and the option orm_mode(https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/model_config/#options) ?

Comment: easy way is to use https://art049.github.io/odmantic/